# How to pass a dynamically changing string to a script task?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

I have a SSIS solution and package. The package includes a Script task that sends a message via API call to Telegram. So far this works ok as the package receives two variables: API token and ChatId. Inside the package I have temporarily defined a message to send.

My concern here is that I would like to use the same script to send different messages depending on the conditions that occur during package execution and I dont want to have the same script task with a different message inside it. I have been trying to consider package variables but dont really understand how to use them to send variable messages as each script task will require a different variable

This is my control flow so far. As you can see, the script task runs multiple times depending on the task context, requiring different messages to be sent.
[image]

This is the main part of my script task. As you can see I have temporarily set a fixed message and thats the one I would like to be dynamic (think of it as a function parameter)

```
public void Main()
{

    ///TELEGRAM API
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    string urlString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage?chat_id={1}&text={2}&parse_mode=html";
    string apiToken = (String)Dts.Variables["User::TelegramToken"].Value;
    string chatId = (String)Dts.Variables["User::TelegramChatId"].Value;
    string text = "This is the message to be sent";
    urlString = String.Format(urlString, apiToken, chatId, text); 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlString); 
    Stream rs = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); 
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rs); 
    string line = ""; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
            sb.Append(line);
    }
    string response = sb.ToString();
   ///TELEGRAM API

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

EDIT1:I was just thinking about using en Expression task to set a variable before executing the script. Would that be an appropriate alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use an expression task to set the message. These are the changes that I recommend:

1. Put everything before the telegram message into a sequence container and connect that sequence container to the telegram script task
2. Add a string variable at the package level to hold the message
3. Set the message variable with expressions within the sequence container above
4. Replace the hard-coded text with the variable reference

[image]

[image]

```
...
    string text = (String)Dts.Variables["User::Message"].Value;
...
```